# How can run second query based on first query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]Im using two query's, 1st separated one column to two columns and inserted one table and second query (PIVOT) fetching based on inserted table,

1st Query,

```
SELECT A.MDDID, A.DeviceNumber,  
          Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS MetReading
      FROM  (
             SELECT MDDID,DeviceNumber,  
                    CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Httpstring, ':', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS MetReading  
               FROM  [IOTDBV1].[dbo].[MDASDatas] E
               Where E.MDDID = 49101
             ) AS A CROSS APPLY MetReading.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

2nd Query

```
SELECT * FROM 
        (
           Select ID,MDDID,DeviceNumber,ReceivedDate
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ID2
            , SPLT.MR.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS LIST FROM ( 
                        Select ID,MDDID,DeviceNumber,ReceivedDate
                                    , CAST( '<M>'+REPLACE(MeterReading,',','</M><M>')+'</M>' AS XML) AS XML_MR 
                                    From [dbo].[PARSEMDASDatas] E
                                    Where E.MeterReading is Not Null
                                    )E
                                    CROSS APPLY  E.XML_MR.nodes('/M') AS SPLT(MR)
                                    )A
                                    PIVOT
                                    (
                                        MAX(LIST) FOR ID2 IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8])
                                    )PV
```

I want 2nd query run based on first query no need to require table.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "2nd query run based on first query"? You can wrap the first one on a CTE and use it on the 2nd one, or directly as subquery. In the worst case, you can use a cursor to cycle first one's rows and then use the 2nd one, although it's not recommended if you can get away without one.

Comment: Can you provide us actual query where 1st query inserted data into a table and 2nd query use that table in it?

Comment: Hi im added image first table and result query please check

Comment: Hi, shnugo its solve thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is not very clear... And it is a very good example, why you always should add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including DDL, sample data, own attempts, wrong output and expected output. This time I do this for you, please try to prepare such a MCVE the next time yourself...

If I get this correctly, your source table includes a CSV column with up to 8 (max?) values. This might be solved much easier, no need to break this up in two queries, no need for an intermediate table and not even for PIVOT.

```sql
--create a mockup-table to simulate your situation (slightly shortened for brevity)

DECLARE @YourTable TABLE(ID INT,MDDID INT, DeviceNumber VARCHAR(100),MetReading VARCHAR(2000));
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES
 (2,49101,'NKLDEVELOPMENT02','DCPL,981115,247484,9409') --the character code and some numbers
,(3,49101,'NKLDEVELOPMENT02','SPPL,,,,,,,,')            --eigth empty commas
,(4,49101,'NKLDEVELOPMENT02','BLAH,,,999,,');           --A value somewhere in the middle
```

--The cte will return the table *as is*. The only difference is a cast to XML (as you did it too)

```
WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,MDDID
          ,DeviceNumber
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(MetReading,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Casted
    FROM @YourTable t
)
SELECT s.ID
      ,s.MDDID
      ,s.DeviceNumber
      ,s.Casted.value('/x[1]','varchar(100)') AS [1]
      ,s.Casted.value('/x[2]','varchar(100)') AS [2]
      ,s.Casted.value('/x[3]','varchar(100)') AS [3]
      ,s.Casted.value('/x[4]','varchar(100)') AS [4]
      ,s.Casted.value('/x[5]','varchar(100)') AS [5]
      ,s.Casted.value('/x[6]','varchar(100)') AS [6]
      ,s.Casted.value('/x[7]','varchar(100)') AS [7]
      ,s.Casted.value('/x[8]','varchar(100)') AS [8]
FROM Splitted s;
```

the result

```
ID  MDDID   DeviceNumber        1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8
2   49101   NKLDEVELOPMENT02    DCPL    981115  247484  9409    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
3   49101   NKLDEVELOPMENT02    SPPL                            
4   49101   NKLDEVELOPMENT02    BLAH                    999                     NULL    NULL
```

The idea in short:

Each CSV is tranformed to a XML similar to this:

```
<x>DCPL</x>
<x>981115</x>
<x>247484</x>
<x>9409</x>
```

Using a position predicate in the XPath, we can call the first, the second, the third `<x>` easily.

Answer (score 0):

CTE: WITH common_table_expression is answer

you can prepare some data in first query and user in second

```
 WITH cte_table AS
    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM sys.objects
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM cte_table
    where name  like 'PK%'
```